# Should I use nginx+uwsgi or apache+modwsgi?

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-wsgi, uwsgi, ckan

Looking at the [CKAN deployment documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html), there are several web server options:

> - Apache with the modwsgi Apache module proxied with Nginx for caching
> - Apache with the modwsgi Apache module
> - Apache with paster and reverse proxy
> - Nginx with paster and reverse proxy
> - Nginx with uwsgi

I'm wondering what the merits are of using Apache/modwsgi over Nginx/uwsgi, and how much value Nginx's proxying adds.

The *core* question, I guess, is if I wanted to avoid using two separate web servers in a single installation, what should I consider when choosing one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The CKAN Tech Team document one particular config: apache/modwsgi + nginx reverse proxy. They encourage people to use that, so that when difficulties occur we can fix them as a community.

I'm not clued up enough to give technical arguments between uwsgi and modwsgi. I think there are some CKAN sites on uwsgi and it being more modern there may be some technical advantages. However the installs I've worked with have mostly been apache/modwsgi + nginx reverse proxy. That's probably more down to familiarity and the blessing of the CKAN tech team than anything else.

However I believe nginx is better than apache2 for SSL/TLS termination. We found it was far simpler to configure SSL/TLS, with plenty of new best practices to keep up with in the past few years. And last time I looked several years ago there was an argument that the asynchronous design avoided e.g. slow loris attacks. So I think having nginx on your front-end makes a lot of sense.

You suggest having two HTTP servers is too much, but I think nginx is pretty low overhead and isn't usually a concern.

paster is a toy - no-one uses it for servers.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm aware of the recommended setup in the documentation (apache/modwsgi + nginx), and that's what we generally use; I just had a client query the configuration, citing potentially greater attack surface (two code-bases that could be potentially vulnerable, rather than just the one) and extra complexity, and they proposed sending their AWS loadbalancer forwards direct to Apache and cutting out nginx. The main reason for my question is because I think there is *some* validity to their query, and wanted to better understand any rationale, rather than just accept it at face value.